# Is it possible to set the priority for the main thread?

Tags: java

As we know that even main is also a thread. So just for the curiosity, is it possible to set the priority for the main thread?

Comment: I didn't think of any ways to try till Codemwnci's answer:(..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried

```
Thread.currentThread().setPriority();
```

Comment: but, thread priority is set set before thread start. how we set the thread priority of main method ?

Answer (score 0):

Its worth noting that this is just a hint to the OS and unless you are administrator or root it might not do anything.  Even then it may not help very much. setPriority() is harmless AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, generally setting the priority of a running thread will have no effect. An old trick was to always kick off another thread and abandon main. Indeed this is what the Sun/Oracle JVM now does on Linux in order to change the stack size.

Setting the priority of a thread is typically misguided. Many JRE versions will ignore it altogether.